# What's the difference between CRS 4326, CRS 4978, and CRS 4979?

Tags: coordinate-system

CRS 4326, 4978, and 4979 are all based on WGS84.

- 4326 is called "geographic 2D"
- 4978 is called "geocentric"
- 4979 is called "geographic 3D"

What are the differences between these three?

And why are we using "geographic 2D" (i.e. CRS 4326) for the coordinates?

Comment: Check this Q&A: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23660/difference-between-geographic-3d-and-geocentric-crs